# Get a row from QStringListModel (from qml)

Tags: qml, qstringlistmodel

I found multiple answers on how to do it from C++, but not from QML.

How is it possible to get a specific (based on index) row from QStringListModel? I tried expressions that worked from other models, but it did not work for QStringListModel. I also tried to use

```
var dataRow = myModel.data(rowNumber)
```

But it returned "undefined".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `myModel.data` you are calling [`QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data).
This methods takes a `QModelIndex` and an optional int for the role.
The display role is what you want when you query a `QStringListModel` so you don't need to specify the role parameter.
However you do need to specify the index parameter with a valid `QModelIndex`. You can get one from the model with [`QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index)

So in your case the correct way to do it would be :
`var dataRow = myModel.data(myModel.index(rowNumber, 0));`

You can call `data` and `index` from QML because both are `Q_INVOKABLE`.